# Last Logged In, in Customers always shows 'Never (Offline)'

Tags: customer, status

The Last Logged In status, in Customers  always shows 'Never (Offline)' Does anyone know how to fix. It says the date an account was created but always shows 'Never (Offline)' as last logged in.

Comment: I have found the answer it is : goto system -> configuration -> advanced -> system -> log and enable log.

Answer (score 15):

Goto system -> configuration -> advanced -> system -> log and enable log.