# Last Logged in returns null

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to get customer last logged in (last visited) date in front end but it returns null . For some users it returns the date which also doesn't seems to be the correct date .
this is what i am using to get last login date .

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();  
 foreach ($collection as $customer) { 
    $logCustomer = Mage::getModel('log/customer')->loadByCustomer($customer);
    $lastVisited = $logCustomer->getLoginAt();
 }
```

Also on back end it shows Last Logged In:   Never (Offline) for most of the users .

Comment: and what is the $customer variable?? How do you get the customer??

Comment: $collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();  foreach ($collection as $customer) { }

Answer (score 0):

Use This code

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();  
 foreach ($collection as $customer) { 
    $logCustomer = Mage::getModel('log/customer')->loadByCustomer($customer);
    $lastVisited = $logCustomer->getLoginAtTimestamp();
 }
```

Comment: getLoginAtTimestamp() and getLoginAt() returning same result .

Answer (score 0):

Last login date stores in table log_customer

```
select * from log_customer;
```

If Magento on back end shows Last Logged In: Never (Offline, it means that customer never logins before and log_customer has not data for this customer.

Comment: There are customers which completed orders and on backend it shows Logged In : Never . Also log_customer table contains data .

Answer (score 0):

If you have data in `log_customers` and your code is not returning correct result, could it be there is some module overwriting this default behavior?

Answer (score 0):

For those how are facing the same problem, getting null from $logCustomer->getLoginAt() function, take a look at this link below:

[Last Logged In, in Customers always shows 'Never (Offline)'](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/75050/last-logged-in-in-customers-always-shows-never-offline)

goto system -> configuration -> advanced -> system -> log and enable log.

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE and thanks for your  contribution. Since the question boils down to the same problem as the one you linked, I flagged it as duplicate now.